# Web App - manifest.json not applied if it's in a sub-path

Tags: reactjs, nginx, web-applications

I am attempting to create a react based web app. I got it working the way I wanted, and it behaved as a web app the way I expected -- for now, that means to me that on my phone, from chrome, if from the chrome menu I choose 'Add to Home screen' it shows up as if it were an app (showing up with its own icon & launching in a new window outside of chrome).

After getting that working, I decided to reorganize so that the path would be the way I wanted it - from **mydomain.com** -> **apps.mydomain.com/appName**. I moved the code to the proper directory, and when I browse there I see my "app".

I noticed an issue right away where the static assets were not loading, I fixed that by adding a symlink in **www/mydomain.com** pointing to **www/mydomain.com/appName/static**. At this point, I thought my app was properly reorganized.

Unfortunately, when I tried "add to Home screen" from chrome, it now makes a regular shortcut, which to me seems to indicate the manifest.json isn't being applied. This all adds up to me to be a fundamental issue I don't understand with code organization for sub-paths which gave me pause.

**So my question is:** *What do I need to do to properly host my web app in a sub-path?*

**Notes:**

- I am using **nginx** - I am suspicious that my issue lies in configuration there, and if more info on my configuration there is needed, I can provide it.
- Regarding the change to **apps.** - sorry if it obfuscates the problem somewhat, to note I just added an alias - thus **apps.mydomain.com** appears to be equivalent to **mydomain.com** - I only noted it in case that assumption was wrong and part of the problem.
- Pardon my question language if it's wrong, I am new-ish to web, and may not be using the lingo properly - that also is why I am probably having difficulty just googling this.

Thanks!

Comment: Another note, I would like to keep apps.mydomain.com still a valid website. My thought being I could link to my apps from there.

When I copied my manifest up a directory and changed it to reference down a directory, it did work - but that is unideal behavior due to the above note about apps.mydomain.com becoming un-usable and because other apps I put in other paths, ie apps.mydomain.com/app2 would then not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. My app was made with create-react-app, and in the **package.json** I edited the homepage to be my path.

Found this out from here:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths